# See which functions of a chrome extension are being called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, script-debugging

I'm trying to understand the code of a chrome extension I did not write. This extension is active the entire time and working in background. Now I'd like to see which functions are being called on the different actions I do on websites.

I got so far that I have to use the Debugging Console which I open with Ctrl+Shift+I, but how exactly do I have to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using the "Event Listener Breakpoints".  You can get to it under the sources tab on the right hand side.  Just expand desired section.

For example, if you want to track a click event on a button, expand Event Listener Breakpoints -> Expand Mouse -> Select 'click'.  Upon clicking the button in the tool, it should stop in the code where the action is handled.

It is worth noting that the code will probably be minified, so reading it might not be trivial.